# Rails 4.0.0 is not sending proper response after using a jQuery $.get()

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

I have the following issue: I'm using Rails 4.0.0 with jQuery, and I have a comment that I'm trying to delete. My javascript is as follows:

```
  // deleting a comment
   $('#delete_comment').click( function(event) {                              
       event.preventDefault()
       var elem = $(this).parents().eq(3)                                     
       var url = event.target.href                                            
       $.get(url, function(data) {                                            
         elem.empty()                                                         
         elem.remove()                                                        
       })                                               
   })
```

I've also tried using $(document).on('click'...etc) before each click trigger...and I have $(document).ready (function () { .. encompassing all my click events

My HTML is:

```
 <div class="comment row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2">
        <h5><small>another goof commend </small>Alexandra</h5>
         <h6><small><a autofocus="autofocus" href="/comment_destroy?comment%5Bentry_id%5D=164&amp;id=161" id="delete_comment">delete</a></small></h6>
   </div>
</div>
```

When I click to delete a comment the first time, I get the following response from the server:

```
Started GET "/comment_destroy?comment%5Bentry_id%5D=164&id=160" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-29 19:40:09 -0700
Processing by CommentsController#destroy as */*
  Parameters: {"comment"=>{"entry_id"=>"164"}, "id"=>"160"}
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  Comment Load (4.6ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "160"]]
  Entry Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "entries".* FROM "entries" WHERE "entries"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "164"]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.3ms)  DELETE FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."id" = $1  [["id", 160]]
   (0.5ms)  COMMIT
  Rendered comments/destroy.html.erb within layouts/application (0.1ms)
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Completed 200 OK in 25ms (Views: 12.1ms | ActiveRecord: 7.4ms)
```

This is the response I want, and the comment is deleted without reloading the page...

However, when I delete a second comment, I get the following response:

```
Started GET "/comment_destroy?comment%5Bentry_id%5D=164&id=162" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-29 19:41:00 -0700
Processing by CommentsController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"comment"=>{"entry_id"=>"164"}, "id"=>"162"}
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  Comment Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "162"]]
  Entry Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "entries".* FROM "entries" WHERE "entries"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "164"]]
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.3ms)  DELETE FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."id" = $1  [["id", 162]]
   (0.6ms)  COMMIT
  Rendered comments/destroy.html.erb within layouts/application (0.1ms)
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Completed 200 OK in 12ms (Views: 5.6ms | ActiveRecord: 2.7ms)


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-29 19:41:00 -0700
```

The main difference between these is the `Processing by CommentsController#destroy as */*`
on the first request, and the `Processing by CommentsController#destroy as HTML` on the second response.

Weirdly, only comments on the top row yield the response I want.

I've completely removed Turbolinks from my Rails app, and I've tried a number of other things, such as using jquery-turbolinks... I've read numerous other questions about how to get Rails 4.0.0 working with jQuery, but there doesn't seem to be a consistent answer, and nothing that's been suggested has worked for me so far. I've spent countless hours debugging this issue and I'm at my wits end.

Does anyone have any conclusive, definite, sure to work advice on using jQuery with Rails? Is it just not recommended? How did the core team release Turbolinks with Rails without knowing it's so buggy with jQuery? I'm so confused! Please help :)

Answer (score 0):

Conclusive, definite, sure to work advice on using jQuery with Rails (in particular, using AJAX):

If you happen to be including jQuery manually, instead, use `gem 'jquery-rails'` in your gemfile, and include the line `//= require jquery` in your application.js file.

Make sure you use jquery_ujs (include the line `//= require jquery_ujs` in your application js file)

Follow the doco at https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki to get your delete functionality working using the data-remote attribute on your link, and allowing jquery ujs to handle as much of the ajax stuff as possible.

That jquery_ujs library will save you much time and pain. And it should work just fine with TurboLinks.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the answer. I already had: gem 'jquery-rails', "~> 2.3.0" in my Gemfile and //= require jquery_ujs and //= require jquery
 in my application.js file. I'll take a look at the link

Comment: Any particular version of jQuery that works? or does it matter?

Comment: I'm using jquery-rails (3.0.4) and haven't had problems with it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, finally made it work. The reason why only the first comment was getting deleted is because I had an #id tag for each comment, and in HTML rules, only one element can have an id, so I modified it to a class:

```
<%= link_to 'delete', comment_destroy_path(:comment=>entry.id=>comment.entry_id}, :id=>comment.id), :class=>"delete_comment" %>
```

and in my javascript I did the following:

```
 // deleting a comment
 $(document.ready(function() { 
    $(a.delete_comment').click ( function (event) {
      var elem = $(this).parents().eq(3);
      var url = event.target.href;
      $.ajax({
         url: url,
         beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token',$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))},
         success: function () {
              elem.empty();
              elem.remove();
         }
       })
       event.preventDefault()
    })
 })
```

In my config/routes.rb file I have:

```
controller :comments do 
  get 'comment_destroy' => :destroy
end
```

Since before I was calling it with a DELETE and it was processing a GET for some reason..

Comment: Moving forward, you should still check out jquery_ujs. It'll save you time in future. It's really nice.

Comment: You should check out this video on it: http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript

Comment: Okay, cool, thanks :) I already have it included but I'm not too familiar with it. I'll take a look